# Where are all installed Windows quality update KB IDs stored in the Windows Registry?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

Where are all installed [Windows quality update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/managed-desktop/operate/windows-quality-update-overview) KB IDs stored in the [Windows Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry)?

Are all Windows quality update KBs all stored in the same place in the Windows Registry, or is it necessary to use [WMI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-start-page) or some other mechanism to obtain the full list of installed Windows quality update KBs?

Comment: This question belongs on [su], as it is not programming-related.

Comment: Why do you need the registry?  The update history is plainly available in Windows 10 / 11 in Settings, Windows Update.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Windows doesn’t really have to know every update only know which updates were installed and only then if it’s not reset

Comment: In order to satisfy a requirement for some software I am working on, I need to be able to programmatically retrieve all of the installed KBs on a Windows computer. If I know where in the Windows Registry all of the installed KBs can be obtained, then I can use this information to write code that satisfies this requirement. Given the way I phrased my question, the people on Stack Overflow judged this SE site was more appropriate, as the question itself is independent from programming logic.

Comment: SE should have closed your Q as a duplicate, I think, though they were also right that it is not about programming, per se. Here's a duplicate that appears to still be valid on the SE site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102900/registry-key-location-for-security-update-and-hotfixes

Comment: @ShaneBishop - Only the current cumulative update is actually ever installed. Newer cumulative include the contents of previous cumulative updates.

Comment: @music2myear - That existing question was from before Windows 7 received cumulative updates. Prior to one specific Windows 7 update, all prior updates, were indeed kept installed until they were superseded.  This is the reason it took so long to update a Windows 7 machine prior to the date where cumulative updates did in fact exist on Windows 7.

Comment: The keys in the other post do still exist, and they contain lists of KBs installed. FWIW. It probably means some intelligence is required to figure out the actual update level. Frankly, using a NET function (what PowerShell pulls from) seems the best way to actually accomplish this from a programmatic perspective, rather than polling the registry.

Comment: > In order to satisfy a requirement for some software I am working on, I need to be able to programmatically retrieve all of the installed KBs on a Windows computer.
This does not imply that you need to query the registry for that purpose, other methods might be available.